# How to display double quotes in Postgres/pgAdmin column

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, quoted-identifier

In my new workplace, some of table have column name wrapped with double quote and some of them is not. It's somewhat confusing for me to do some query. So I want to try standardize that to wrapped all column with double quote.

But I really don't know is this column have double quote or not until i do query with the table. Is there any settings to display whether column is wrapped by double quote ot not in postgres especially in pgAdmin since I use that?

*since there are many table there. i think its really time consuming to check 1 by 1 with query

Comment: You can always use double quotes, if you need a "standard". But for greatest convenience, only use table and column names that contain only lower case ASCII characters, digits and underscores. Then you can live completely without double quotes.

Comment: The rules for quoting identifiers are documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: Double-quoting everything is an option in some ERD tools, and my guess is the schema was generated, in part, using one of them.